# Blocking frames from displaying a site from another domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, userscripts

I am currently creating a script for [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) for which i have to create an iframe and display a site from a different domain, but it is not loading.

So I tryd it on another site and it worked - 
So my question: Is there a setting which controlls this behaviour?

If you need any more information please tell me

Comment: Sounds like it's a mixed security issue, like trying to embed an HTTPS iframe on an HTTP site or vice versa. There's really nothing to do for that other than using the same protocol, if available.

Comment: Is there a possibility to have an HTTP iframe on an HTTPS site?

Comment: Most browsers will block those frames by default. Maybe it supports HTTPS; one trick is to use a protocol-less URL (`//somedomain.com/some/url`) so it will use HTTP or HTTPS depending on the host page. If it doesn't support HTTPS at all, you're SOL because the user will have to manually accept the non-secure resource.